# Trying to apply curve bevel to curve

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, bevel

Newbie here. I'm trying to apply a bevel (curve) to an outline (curve) and it's basically blowing up. I think it's because the scale is off or point of view/origin but I'm not sure. Below is what is going on, before the application and after:

[image: Before]

[image: After]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The chicken object seems to have its scale applied at [1,1,1], and so does the bevel object so that doesn't seem to be the issue. Check the *Radius* property of the Chicken curve. Enter *Edit Mode* on the Chicken curve,  select all vertex and on the Tool Shelf on left press the *Set Curve Radius* and set them all to [1]

Comment: Hello again, Duarte! Thanks for the help. I just checked the curve radius and it was set to 1 as well. - Screenshot uploaded

Comment: I did set the origin to 0,0,0 on both the chicken curve and bevel curve, is this correct?

Comment: You shouldn't have. The origin for the chicken is irrelevant, but for the bevel object must be placed sanely relative to the bevel object own geometry, not the scene coordinates. The origin point is the point that will be placed exactly over the chicken curve when the section is "swept" over its shape.

Comment: Your chicken also seems to have been converted to mesh and back, loosing much of its properties and yielding worse results.

Comment: Ok, I re-imported the SVG, made sure it was not converted to mesh, set the origin for the bevel curve as shown above. All scales are at 0,0,0. still getting the weirdness..

Comment: Post a blend file impossible to know without looking

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1as3en76lafus4z/chicken_latest.blend?dl=0

Comment: Your chicken scale is *not applied* (not set to [1,1,1]) and after you do so, your chicken curve radius *will not* be set to [1] to all vertex (which you must manually set as described above by actually pressing enter on the radius value box). Also your bevel curve is wider than the double stroke, causing self intersections

Comment: I posted the error message I'm receiving when using ctrl + A to set the scale.

Comment: You are trying to apply rotation, not scale. Apply the scale not rotation

Comment: ok I applied scale, went to curve radius, entered that manually and re-applied bevel with same result.

Comment: I think I'm going to start fresh with a shiny new single stroke drawing and try from there...

Comment: GOT IT - not sure what was going on with that imported vector image but it's working now, thank you very much for your help with this, it's a universal "skill" that I can reuse and I would not have discovered it otherwise. Thank you very much!

Comment: If you put your response in answer form I'll mark it as answered